# Eclipse not deploying Android apps on device or Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I just updated the SDK and ADT, I did not uninstall the previous version I had, I just installed "on top" of it.

Now I cannot get Eclipse to deploy Android apps to a device or to the emulator

as a side note, I am also working with Rhomobile, and those apps get deployed to device and to the emulator, so eclipse IS working somehow.

I have looked around, and tried disabling the "build automatically" option and the clean build projects. But nothing has worked to far.

I downloaded the latest SDk, ADT and I am using NDK r5b because of rhodes, but it was working fine before the update so I don't think the NDK is the problem.

This is what I get:

```
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] ------------------------------
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] Android Launch!
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] Performing com.rhomobile.SASNativeStart.SASNativeStartActivity activity launch
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'HT07XP800811'
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] Uploading SASNativeStart.apk onto device 'HT07XP800811'
[2011-10-24 03:21:27 - SASNativeStart] Installing SASNativeStart.apk...
```

And it gets stuck there forever.

The progress bar just says:

> Android SDK Content Loader (Finished)

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the emulator's Console logs show?

Comment: I just added the console log, that is for the device. For the emulator it gets stuck at the same point

Comment: if its built the .apk file (look in your /bin directory) try installing the apk from the command line `adb install bin/my.apk` see if you get the same problem.

Comment: The app gets installed correctly by doing that. The problem is with Eclipse's deploy

Comment: if you create a new virtual device, does it have the same problem? Or perhaps try a different app? If you restart the android emulator, and eclipse, does it still occur?

Comment: I did create a virtual device and tried different apps but the same thing happens. I have restarted the emulator, eclipse, computer and phone, but the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem look like the problem of the ADT Plugin. so what you need to do is like uninstall all previous version of the ADT from Eclipse. and try to install the newer/ latest version of the ADT plugin which is available at [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I unistalled the ADT plugin, restart eclipse, and installed again